# Debug shortcuts in VS Code on a Mac

Tags: mac, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code on my Linux machine and I find it a great tool. However, on a Mac (MacBook Pro), I have some issues in a debugging mode. MacBook uses the F keys for its own purposes (changing brightness, volume, etc.). Then in order to use, for example, F5 (continue) or F10 (step over), I have to press fn+F5 or fn+F10, which is fairly cumbersome. Is there a way to make the shortcuts work so that only one key is assigned to the debug functions (preferably the F keys)?

Answer (score 5):

You have two options here, changing the settings for the Function keys to standard function keys, or re-bind the keyboard shortcut for Debug functionalities in VS Code.

### Use F1, F2, etc as standard function keys

In MacOS,

1. Go to `System Preferences`
2. Click on `Keyboard`
3. Go to the `Keyboard` tab
4. Tick the option that says `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys`

[image: Function keys on the Mac]

### Re-map the Debug key

In your [VS Code keybindings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings), add the following lines. Change the keyboard shortcut to whatever you prefer

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+cmd+s",
    "command": "workbench.action.debug.stop",
    "when": "inDebugMode"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+cmd+s",
    "command": "workbench.action.debug.stepOver",
    "when": "inDebugMode"
  },
```